# I want to access one of its properties (as default property) when I use an object reference. Is it possible?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
    public class NodeData<T>
    {
        public string Name;
        public T Value;
        public NodeData(string name, T value){
             this.Name = name;
             this.Value = value;
        }
    }
    NodeData data = new NodeData<int>("test",111);
```

How is this possible to access Value of this object using `data` instead of `data.Value`

I mean by `var a = data;` a should be int 111 not a NodeData object. Is it possible? Therefore usage of my objects is much more simpler.

Comment: Name and value are the properties of the object of the class. Data is the reference to the object of the class. You're getting the attribute value of the object when you call data.value. It might be possible to get the value via data, but not via that class as is.

Comment: You can override ToString() method of NodeData class by: return Value.ToString(). Of course, the T type should have override method ToString also if it is you custom type (class, struct...) not a basic type (int, string...)

Comment: @Reisclef I understand it, But I'm looking for a default property or something like that if such a thing exist!

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I misunderstood. I think the answer with tostring()  being overridden is your best bet if you want to return that via just data. If it's a different type you might be able to convert it. As far as I'm concerned that's just OOP as it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the class you could have an operator:

```
public static implicit operator T(NodeData<T> data)
{
  return data.Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = new NodeData<int>("test", 111);
int a = data; // OK
```

It will not work with `var` in the `a` declaration.

---

Now I read your question before you edited it. Suppose a method is overloaded like this:

```
void WriteLine(object o);
void WriteLine(int i);
```

then with `data` as before, the call:

```
WriteLine(data)
```

will be resolved as follows (simplified): The first overload is applicable by simple reference conversion since `NodeData<>` derives from `object`. And the second overload is also applicable by your user-defined `implicit` conversion operator. Since both overloads apply, we need to try to find the "better" one of the two. The `int` version is better because `int` is implicitly convertible to `object` (by a boxing conversion) while `object` is not implicitly convertible to `int` (not all objects are integers).

So in the end, the `int` overload is chosen at binding-time.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. But I have another question too. Does `data1 + data2` runs very slower than `data1.Value + data2.Value` ?

Comment: @a.toraby My guess is, no, it will run at the same speed. I assume you built the application in Release mode (with optimizations enabled) and run it without the Visual Studio Debugger attached. In that case I believe the call to your operator (which is just an ordinary method to the run-time) will be [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). So as I said, I think the speed will be the same, under the conditions I mentioned.